# Code first ASPNET Identity tables

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, ef-code-first, asp.net-identity

I have this setup. It is a setup with 3 projects:

1. DAL
2. BLL
3. WEB

In the DAL I have my models which I use with Code First.
In my BLL I call my DAL
In my WEB I use my DLL to get access to the data.

I want to use ASPNET IDENTITY so I registered a user in my WEB project. With this the correct tables are created (AspNetUsers,...).

When I update my database in my DAL project all works well and the tables are added in the database next to the IDENTITY tables.

In my DataContext.cs I do my OnModelCreating where I create the tables like this (which I do for all my tables):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Klant>().ToTable("Klant");
```

I then make a DbSet for the "Klanten":

```
public DbSet<Klant> Klanten { get; set; }
```

All of the above works perfectly...BUT...
My question is..how can I access the ASPNET IDENTITY tables in my DAL project? How can I create something simular so I can make a foreign key from my UserInfo table to the AspNetUsers table?

Comment: You need to have your application context inherit from IdentityDbContext or you can clone a class into your app context for the user table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok solved it. I recreated the tables with create a new Entity data model and choosing the option code first from database.
I then chose the AspNet tables and created the file. Simple copy and paste in my own datacontext and done.